# What's the best way to check row existence in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql

I need to know which is the best way to check for a row:

Without column; only just a number:

```
SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE users.id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

With column and database( users.id )

```
SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

With column and without database

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

With all fields( obviously inefficient ):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

And It is recommended to use the sentence "limit" when the sentence "exists" is used?

Example with limit:

```
SELECT products.* FROM products
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE users.id = products.user LIMIT 1
)
```

Example without limit:

```
SELECT products.* FROM products
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE users.id = products.user
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
select count(*) records
from users
where id = 1
```

Then I would check the value of records in my application.

Comment: Or even better `count(id)`